# bounds of stopped martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

Let $M$ be a continuous  martingale

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Note that $$\tau:=\inf\left\{t\in [0,T]:\left|M_t\right|\ge\varepsilon\right\}$$ is a stopping time with $$\left|M^\tau\right|\le\varepsilon\;.\tag1$$

Why is the stopped process $M^{\tau}$
bounded by epsilon. $\tau$ is the first time $|M_t| \geq \varepsilon$, so the stopped process cannot be bounded by this constant. What do I mix up?

Comment: The stopped process is $M^\tau_t:=M_{t\wedge\tau}$. We always have $t\wedge\tau\le\tau$.

Comment: But $|M_{\tau}| \geq \varepsilon$ and not $\leq$?

Comment: Indeed, but $M_t<\varepsilon$ before $\tau$, and $t\mapsto M_t$ is *continuous* by assumption.

Comment: I think at this point I have trouble to understand this. We stop the process at $\tau$. Why do we consider the time before?

Comment: You mean $M_t < \varepsilon \Rightarrow lim_{t \rightarrow \tau} M_t =M_{\tau} < \varepsilon$

Comment: No, we have that $|M_t| < \varepsilon$ implies $\lim_{t \rightarrow \tau} |M_t| = |M_\tau| \le \varepsilon$ because of continuity.  Since $|M_\tau| \ge \varepsilon$ and $|M_\tau| \le \varepsilon$ we have that $|M_\tau| = \varepsilon$.

Comment: @user6247850: Thank you:) Why do we get $\leq$ instead of < by passing to the limit?

Comment: For the same reason that $\frac1n>0$ gives $0\ge0$ when passing to the limit. Note that one needs $\tau\in(0,\infty]$ to show that $|M_\tau|\le\varepsilon$. I assume you forgot to mention that $M_0=0$.

Comment: If $\tau=\infty $ then $|M_{t}| < \varepsilon  \forall t\in [0,T]$